# Load File From Local Gem in IRB

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a cloned a ruby gem to my client.

According to the docs here (https://github.com/Jbur43/usps_counties)

I have to `require 'usps_counties'` in order to load it.

So my path is /usps_counties. From there I load irb and try requiring the usps_counties file, but it can't find it.

I then go to /usps_counties/lib (the file lives in the lib directory), load irb and try requiring it but cant find it.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 9):

If you want to require a local file or gem in irb, I like this method:

```
irb -I lib -r usps_countries
```

This allows you to then require the module in your new irb instance:

```
require 'usps_countries'
```

Options used:

```
-I path           Specify $LOAD_PATH directory
-r load-module    Same as `ruby -r'
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a relative path?

> require './usps_counties'
>
> [require_relative](https://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/require_relative) 'usps_counties'

Comment: Oh, I tried in the usps_counties/lib directory, with require_relative 'usps_counties', and it found it.
Or else with : require_relative 'usps_counties/lib/usps_counties'